# pytest verbose output explanation

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I am using pytest-django to run unit tests I made. When I use the `-v` flag I get an output like:

```
dashboard/apps/excel_import/tests.py::ExcelImportTestCase::test_multiple_excel PASSED [ 50%]
dashboard/apps/excel_import/tests.py::ExcelImportTestCase::test_specific_excel PASSED [100%]
```

I can't find in the pytest docs, or anywhere else on google, what the `PASSED [ 50%]` means. I have 4 asserts in that specific test, does it mean I passed 2 and failed 2? if so then why doesn't it tell me I failed some tests?

I don't know if this is relevant but I am also using python-cov for code coverage. The code coverage results claim 100% of that file is being run, so it doesn't seem like only half the tests were run or something of the sort.

If anyone know what the `PASSED [ 50%]` means I will be very grateful for the insight. Thanks in advance for any help available!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"`PASSED`" means the listed test passed.  `[ 50%]` is how many of the tests have been run so far.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I still don't understand how it can tell me that the test passed if only 50% of the asserts were run. Or do you mean that 50% of the total amount of tests that I wrote have run, and since this was test 1 out of 2 to be run, and it finished, than 50% of my tests were run (as apposed to asserts within a test)?

Comment: @OhaNoch: 50% of the total amount of tests were run.